# Azure VPN Keeps Dropping Connection And Won't Come Back Up

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn

I have a site-to-site network setup in Azure to allow my servers in Azure connect to some local resources.  The gateway is setup with static routing (policy based).  If the connection is inactive for 5 minutes, Azure will bring down the connection automatically.  This is fine, but for some reason Azure won't bring back up the connection if it has any attempted traffic from Azure -> Local.  The only way to bring the connection back up is to generate traffic from Local -> Azure.

When the connection goes down I can't ping or telnet to my local servers from Azure.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Disclaimer: I am not a network engineer, so I apologize for any improper use of terms.

Comment: verify TTL settings for both IPSec phases. Azure and your appliance must have the same values.

Comment: @BrunoFaria Can you explain how to do that in Azure?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You can't change Azure. Azure is pre-defined. You change it on your side, but they have to match Azure. Configs here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/